# Error L6218E undefined symbol _asm (referred from main.o)

Tags: linker, keil, stm32f4

I'm facing a linker error. I wrote the following inline Assembly code in Keil µVision5,

```
_asm("NOP");
_asm("NOP");
```

and I got the following error:
`.\RAM\STM32F439_Template.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol _asm (referred from main.o).`

I included the header file "stm325439xx.h" in the program.

Could anyone help me fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To make this code work, you either need to include the header where a macro `_asm` is defined, or else if it is built in to some compiler then select the correct compiler in the project settings (Keil tools support multiple different compilers).

However, the portable solution is to not use this code but rather to include `"stm32f4xx.h"` and then use `__NOP()`, which is correct for many compilers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. I have just fixed the error by putting two consecutive underscores "__" instead of one "_" before the letters "asm". "__asm" (with two consecutive underscores) is the correct symbol while "_asm" (with only one underscore) is undefined. In this question I used the wrong symbol with only one underscore "_asm". That was why I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,it's __(two consecutive underscores instead of one)